# find all string in a string and use it

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string like this into my page php:

```
$string = 'this is a test for @john and I can do all @mike';
```

I would like to take this string find all string inside it after `@` and use it to find the name of the user with that user id if exist and convert into a link to become something like this:

```
 $string = 'this is a test for <a href="/user?id=111">@john</a> and I can do all <a href="/user?id=112">@mike</a>';
```

How to take all string and use it to find the id of that user and after substitute the original string with a link?

I know that using `preg_match` I can take the string inside it but how to use this string? ando how construct this expression to take the name after `@`?

Thanks

Comment: `preg_match_all` to get all the `@` tokens then create an array of replacements use `str_replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function, say, `link()`, that takes the string `john` and returns the appropriate link:

```
preg_replace_callback('/@(\w+)/', function($matches) {
    return link($matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

Or, for older PHP versions:

```
preg_replace('/@(\w+)/e', 'link(\'$1\')', $string);
```

Comment: Ok but I have to find the id of the user dynamically I don't know which user I have "tagged" I want to take the string after @ make a query foreach match, retrieve its id and aftyer replace into the string

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, exactly. `link()` would be called with `john` as an argument. You can use `john` to find out whatever you need to find out, make database queries, etc, and return link.

Comment: and in your function inside the function before return I have to make the query? I don't understand how to create a link because I have to take id from database @rid

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, what do you need to take the ID from the database? I presume you need to make a query, use `john` in it, and that query would return the ID, correct?

Comment: yes I want to take john(and after mike) send a query with that name retrieve the id (if exist a user with that name) and create the link if is possible @rid

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, then the `link()` function could do just that - make a database query, obtain the ID, and return `<a href=".../?id=$theIdYouObtained">...</a>`. As you can see, the function is called with `john`, `mike`, etc, as an argument.

Comment: ok I have understand but there isn't output? because if is possible I want that return the same original string but with the replace of the link inside is possible?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, that's what `preg_replace()` / `preg_replace_callback()` does: it replaces a regular expression with something else and returns the modified string.

Comment: yes but in this case if I print the variable $string is the same that the original... I expected that was modified by the function

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, the `preg_*` functions do not modify the string in the variable. They return the new string. You can assign the returned value back to `$string` if you want to replace it, something like `$string = preg_...(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `preg_match_all` The following code will extract every word from the string begining with `@` and return it into an array called `$matches`. You can then loop through the array comparing it and conditioning to it suit your needs.

```
$string = 'this is a test for @john and I can do all @mike';

preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(@\w+\b)/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'this is a test for @john and I can do all @mike';
$result = preg_replace('/([^@]+)([^\s]+)/simx', '$1<a href="yourlink">$2</a>', $string);

echo $result;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
this is a test for <a href="yourlink">@john</a> and I can do all <a href="yourlink">@mike</a>
```

Comment: No, my link is to take after match because I don't know the id of the user after the @, I have first take all match user, take for every its id and after replace with a link

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function.

After that I would loop over the matches and retrieve their IDs, and I generate the appropriate link for each of them, storing them in an array let's call it `$links`.

At this point I would have two arrays:

1. `$matches` - which would contain all the occurrences of my pattern
2. `$links` - which would contain all the respective links in a 1-1 correspondence.

Finally I would use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in the following way:

`preg_replace($matches, $links, $initial_string);`

This will replace each item in `$matches` that finds in the `$initial_string` with the corresponding item from `$links`.

I hope I helped you. Maybe later I will be able to provide some code as well.